# BoxPlots with log scale in Julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using `Plots`.
When I use the log scale for the x-axis, the plot does not seem to be nice.
The width of the box is not arranged.

Do you have any idea to overcome this?

```
boxplot([10 100 1000], [randn(10).+10 randn(10).+20 randn(10).+30], color="gray", legend=false, bar_width=50)
```

[image]

```
boxplot([10 100 1000], [randn(10).+10 randn(10).+20 randn(10).+30], color="gray", legend=false, bar_width=10, xscale=:log10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using StatsPlots

boxplot([10 100 1000], [randn(10).+10 randn(10).+20 randn(10).+30];
    color="gray", legend=false, bar_width=[2 20 200], xscale=:log10)
```

Currently, the `boxplot` function seems to have been migrated to `StatsPlots.jl`.
You can specify the width of individual bars by giving a series to `bar_width`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIDjL.png)